# Save configurations of running containers in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can't find a solution for the next case:

I have a docker and running on it through a Docker-Compose a set of containers; The state of the containers changed during operation;

For the purpose of the test, I want to reinstall the doctors and put another set of containers, but I do not want to lose the condition and configuration of those that I have launched now;

Can I create any archive from current containers / images and generate `docker-compose.yaml` to run them?

Comment: There is `docker commit` to save the current container as a new image. But it's not a good idea to do that, if it's avoidable. You should try to change your setup, to not have to do that. For example, using volumes to persist data.

Comment: You can also use the `docker-compose -f` option to specify an alternate Compose YAML file; `docker-compose -f config-2.yml up`.  That would give you a way to check all of the different test configurations into source control.